# Gallery Chat Room privilege page displays placeholder link

Tags: bug, status-completed

The description of the [Create Gallery Chat Room privilege](https://writers.stackexchange.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) says

> How do I create a gallery chat room?
>
> Visit
>
> chat.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this has been resolved in the ensuing time and was just never marked!